# While running spring boot project getting error like NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have Spring boot project with the pom version 2.7.1 and while running getting below error.
I am using spring cloud dependency. My pom dependency like

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency
```

dependency Management:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2020.0.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Error:
   
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwhUP.png)

Error Message::

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:          org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadat

I need this pom version(2.7.1) not lower than this. Any solution?

Comment: Incompatible versions. Spring Cloud 2020 is for Spring Boot 2.4/2.5 you need at least something in the 2021 range. Also remove the version from the `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` as adding the version beats the purpose of the depenency management block.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks but still same issue if i modify the version from 2.4/2.5 to 
   2021.0.3 for  spring cloud . Also i removed the version from spring-boot-starter- 
 cloud-connectors getting error also asking for use the version tag. Here is the details
  i used.
     spring-cloud-azure-dependencies: 
   2021.0.3spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.0-beta.4</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>

Comment: Please don't add code in comments that is unreadable. The error indicates your versions are incompatible, based on the information here that is your cloud dependency, could be if you have more there are more conflicting dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Still same issue after modification of the version for the below dependencies
**spring-cloud-dependencies** to 2021.0.3 
And also i am using the dependency **spring-cloud-azure-dependencies** with the version 6.0.0-beta.4.  i removed the version tag for the dependency **Spring-boot-starter-cloud-connector** and then getting error i have to use the version here.
Not able to find which version is fit for the spring boot project 2.7.1 
Another dependency:  **<groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
   <v>6.0.0-beta.4</v>**

Comment: If you have the error, i keep repeating myself, you still have incompatible versions. Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and find the conflicting versions. Why are you even using some beta version? And as stated please don't add code as comments that is totally unreadable, edit your question instead.